# Running sql command from Command Prompt

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I have a sql command I want to use to connect to my online database

```
mysql -h your_ddbb_server_ip -u your_user
```

I've installed [MySQL installer 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/5.5.html) and ran the program.

After installing I tried running the command from both command prompt and a program called 'MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client'.

Neither program responded to the command.

How and where do I run this?

Comment: You would run that from the command line.  After you installed the MySQL client, did you add mysql.exe to your `PATH`?  If not, that would likely be why it isn't working from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command prompt (`cmd.exe`)

be sure you have the mysql bin folder in the path (the installer prompts for that) so you can just type `mysql.exe` (or just `mysql`).

Otherwise you have to navigate to the MySql bin folder (in my case that's `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin`

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysql -h your_ddbb_server_ip -u your_user
```

This command will launch an interactive shell. If you just want to execute a command you have to specify the `-e argument`

```
mysql -h your_ddbb_server_ip -u your_user-e "SHOW DATABASES"
```