# MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client closes after I input my password

Tags: mysql-cli

I'm a total beginner at this, and I just installed mySQL by following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY&t=3451s). My problem is that the mysql  command line crashes after I input my password without any error messages. It just straights up exits itself after I enter the password. I've tried the following solution based on what I've found on the internet:

1. Windows key + R and type services.msc
2. Double click MySQL80
3. Change its startup type to Automatic

But the steps above don't work for me. What else can I do? (If possible, can you please give me a step-by-step guide?)

Thanks

Comment: These are related to the mysql service, but not to the mysql comand line. The latter is the plain mysql.exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running sql command from Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915018/running-sql-command-from-command-prompt)

Comment: It allowed me to run the sql command from the command line, but when I tried to enter my password it just says "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Then your user name or password is incorrect

Comment: Welp. I just reinstalled it, and put in a new password. Seems like that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled it and made a new password and it worked. :/